# Where is defined the actual value of the AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED for Windows WASAPI?

Tags: windows, wasapi

In audiosessiontypes.h is "typedef enum _AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE" but not exact value of the AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED.

Not found in the Windows 10 SDK or on the Internet.

Comment: Maybe re-tag this as a question about C/C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enum values start at 0 so

```
typedef enum _AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE
{ 
    AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 
    AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE 
} AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE;
```

is effectively the same as

```
typedef enum _AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE
{ 
    AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED = 0, 
    AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE = 1 
} AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE;
```